# "will have become" vs "are"

Tags: tense, future-tense

I've stumbled upon a sentence:

> We can use it until better alternatives will have become available.

Although it sounds valid to me, I believe it conveys the same idea as

> We can use it until better alternatives are available.

Am I missing something? Or is the former a more complicated way to express the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence is grammatically incorrect. It should read, "We can use it until better alternatives become available." So yes, you could also say, "We can use it until better alternatives are available." Using "become" has the nuance of using something until the moment there's an alternative, whereas using "are" suggests alternatives would be more widely available.