# Has finished or will have finished?

Tags: grammar, tense

There's a sentence: I think I must do it before he has finished / he will have finished his project.

What's correct?

Or maybe does it need another tense?

Comment: What would be your own choice, and why? What tenses are used here, and which would you choose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["will have become" vs "are".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129233/will-have-become-vs-are) The choice of verb tense to associate with "anticipated future" actions is the same after ***before*** as after ***until*** in the linked Q. That's to say, we normally use "**Present as Future**" - *do it before he **finishes** his project*.